# In Sketch: Can you fill a closed shape created by an open vector?

Tags: vector, path, sketch-app, fill

I have a series of vectors such as image A, connecting to form a knot, or maze-like design. I want to fill the closed portion as in B. But the fill feature sees the open vector and gives me C.

Image B here is a hack, there's a shape behind the vector paths. It works, but it's imprecise. And inevitably some other program or file format will separate them and show gaps on import/export.

I know in other programs you can select the nodes individually, and then create a fill zone. I can't see how to do that in Sketch.

[image: I have A. I want B. I get C.]

Comment: Its possible but that is EVEN a worse kludge and has even more problems. Just revese on your curve.

Answer (score 1):

No vector software will fill in only the loop like that automatically.  If you apply a fill to an open vector it will try to fill between the start point and end point, as in (C) in your diagram.  One way to do it would be to add another shape under the looped part and fill that.

Here are some screenshots from Inkscape and Illustrator, both also vector image editors, displaying the same behaviour.  This is normal. The fill attribute can only apply to the entire vector. Selecting anchors to fill won't work, that would simply fill the entire vector in Inkscape or Illustrator.

[image]

There are other ways to fill inside loops - for example making a Live Paint object in Illustrator and using the Live Paint Bucket, or using the Paint Bucket tool in Inkscape - but these literally add another vector shape inside the loop, and fill it. There may be something similar in Sketch.  Sorry I can't be more specific, since I don't use that software, but essentially all vector image editors work in the same kind of way.